# I can't see my Oraichain tokens on Metamask

Tags: metamask

I swapped Ethereum for Oriachain tokens on Metamask.
The Oraichain tokens only show up on the computer that I used for the transaction.

My other devices show Ethereum, but not Oraichain.
It doesn't list Oraichain on the list of tokens to add.

How do I get Oraichai to show on all devices?

Comment: https://tokenmint.io/blog/how-to-add-your-custom-erc-token-to-metamask.html

Comment: you should add it manually to each metamask on each computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Oriachain tokens to your metamask?

Here the official procedure: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015489031-How-to-View-See-Your-Tokens-and-Custom-Tokens-in-Metamask